# How can I test aspects of SIM cards?

Tags: simcard

In the past couple of months, I have had a bug in my SIM card. When data limit is reached, the SIM gives me free Internet at the speed of 10kbps. If I then switch my network type from 4g to 3g and back to 4g, the speed is back to normal, and I get free internet. My guess is that there is some local check which determines the speed.

I want to learn and look into what is happening, something like a Burp Suite of SIM cards. Where do I start?

Comment: @Vipul You are asking for tools, and that type of question is off-topic. You are also assuming that a tool such as you describe would tell you what you want to know about "local checks" and assuming that the local checks have anything to do with the speed change. It would not be a local check that changes your speed, but the network you connect to.

Comment: So OP simply made a mistake and is attributing behavior to the SIM card incorrectly. That doesn't mean it's not security-related, just that OP's diagnosis was incorrect. I do agree that this may be off-topic due to being a product recommendation, though...

Comment: @forest absolutely a security issue for the network, not the user. "How can I inspect data/changes on my SIM?" is not a security question,

Comment: i really dont know how it all works.I am just taking a guess that when i switch between network type it performs a local check to determine the speed.When that happens i am able to discard that check and get my normal speed.i just want to figure that out.I dont ask for any tools as such just something like burpsuite.Something that would help me figure what's going on under the hood

Comment: @VipulNair it's not a local check: the network checks what your SIM card provides and determines how you access the network. What it looks like is that your speed is determined by your current connection. You might be able to accomplish the same thing by restarting your phone. There ***is*** a lot to test and check out here, but I doubt that looking at the SIM will provide those details.

Comment: Not the best question to ask here but, anyways, I would recommend you LiveOverflow's Youtube channel which has some videos on SIM cards, it might help you understand what's going on

Comment: I actually saw a little bit of that and thats where i got my question from.I figured people would know know more in here.

Comment: There is no bug in your SIM card. It's your ISP's network mismanagement. SIM cards don't log your usage.

Comment: but there must be a to and fro from my sim to ISP network in order to determine if my Data cap is over or not.Couldnt there be an access control flaw that when bypassed gives me same speeds even after my data cap?

Comment: Your internet usage is controlled by your ISP and not by SIM. You just discovered a bug in internet usage control of your ISP. If you report bit, it will be fixed.